# Are Repositories needed any longer in ASP.net 5 & EF7?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository

I posted a question on github to the EF Team. I got a reply saying it would be better to ask this question here so I will copy and paste it here as we as a link so other can see the few replies on GitHub.

Question: I was doing some research and someone pointed out that Line 24 of the DBContext Class states

> DbContext is a combination of the Unit Of Work and Repository patterns.

Does this mean that we no longer need to abstract EF to a Repository and then use and Interface to inject it into Controllers?

Original post on Github: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4899

The reason I ask this is I seem to get into a spot where im adding a lot of methods to the repository like GetById, GetByName, GetWithIncludesABC, GetWithIncludes123, etc.. and it seems to be dirtying the repo in my mind

Comment: What do you think of [the answer rowanmiller gave?](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4899#issuecomment-200927141) Seems perfectly reasonable to me.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes it was a good answer but i want to see how others feel about the topic before i make a decision to repository or not

Comment: see also https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/09/11/wither-the-repository/ where Bogard argues similarly.

Comment: My take on why EF (and other ORMs) [are not repositories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180501/what-specific-issue-does-the-repository-pattern-solve/13189143#13189143).

Comment: A repository wouldn't have method like GetWithIncludesABC. The repository pattern is an abstraction of, basically, a database table as a collection. Usually, it is possible to query the collection (e.g. by LINQ), and the repository then converts the query into SQL. What you're talking about sounds more like a Data Gateway.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're adding methods to a repository like

```
GetById 
GetByName 
GetWithIncludesABC
GetWithIncludes123
```

Then you're better off *moving to a **Service Layer,*** and letting the Service Layer use EF directly.  EF already has functionality similar to the above methods that you're just endlessly duplicating.

A Service Layer exposes Business Domain methods, and uses [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) to implement them.  For example, you might have a method called `TransferMoney(A, B)`, where A and B are checking accounts.  This allows you to speak the language of your business domain, while the Service Layer handles the CRUD for you.

The only compelling reason I can think of where you might want to have a separate Repository Layer is so that you can mock that repository layer or substitute a different data source for testing purposes.

Comment: However you can mock dbset... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 4):

Robert Harvey said in his answer:

> The only compelling reason I can think of where you might want to have a separate Repository Layer is so that you can mock that repository layer or substitute a different data source for testing purposes.

This is precisely why the Repository Pattern is still relevant. I also disagree with the Entity Framework teams' assertion that they implement the Repository Pattern. Entity Framework is still very much tied to a database. The whole purpose of the Repository Pattern is to decouple and abstract away the exact persistence mechanism used in your application, so that *nothing* from the implementation of data access leaks outside of the repository layer.

If you are using the EF query API outside of the "repository," like in a service object of some sort, I would say you are breaking the pattern.

Now, if it's not a catastrophic problem for database like functionality to leak into your other code, and you can guarantee that you won't need to move some of your CRUD operations to a web service in the future, then using EF directly would be OK.

Basically, Entity Framework takes the place of the [Gateway object](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-repository-design-pattern--net-35804) in the Repository Pattern. I don't view it as a repository itself.

Comment: How does Repository differ from a Service Layer aspect? from what I can find if im returning IQueryable then im essentially a Repository if im returning IEnumerable then im using a service layer. Is this correct? Are Service Layer and Repository Patterns Similar?

Comment: @Loren.Dorez: A Service Layer has *Business Domain-Specific methods,* like `TransferFunds()` and `BuildWidget()`.  A Repository just contains CRUD methods.

Comment: So both a Service Layer and Repository would directly access the DBContext then? So you would put the CRUD in the Repo and Get Methods and other methods in the Service Layer? Am i understandig this correctly?

Comment: The Service Layer might access the Repository, if you have one, instead of EF directly.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Can you show me an example using the Get Methds above? As now im a bit confused sorry.

Comment: Remember, a repository is still CRUD methods.  Why would you write one, and then bypass it by calling EF directly?  That makes no sense.  Note that you can still choose *not* to write one.

Comment: There is also the "R" in CRUD. Complex queries can be encapsulated by the repository. Just delegating to EF for the "CUD" is not that much extra code, and could be encapsulated by a parent class for your repositories, leaving the concrete repository to implement specific kinds of queries so that is hidden from the rest of your application. Then you don't need to mock EF in unit tests.

Comment: Do you consider `void UpdateOrder(Order order)` a business domain-specific method or C/U from CRUD or both?

Answer (score 1):

Repositories seem not needed - Microsoft in their sample backend microservices applications don't use them:

https://github.com/Microsoft/BikeSharing360_BackendServices

The sample BikeSharing app was shown on Connect(); event (I think it can be used as a template for API projects):

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/12/14/connectdemos-2016-bikesharing360-on-github/